# Como realizar Deploy de Api com Composer / SlimFramework

Tags: php, composer, slimframework

Tenho um api funcionando em localhost como eu faço pra enviar ela pra meu ftp? Tenho essas pastas, baixei com composer o slimframwork é só enviar tudo?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da maneira que você organizou as pastas e o `index.php`, sim é só enviar o conteudo da pasta *BackEnd* via FTP para a pasta "root" do servidor HTTP.

Em servidores SHARED e VPS costuma ser a pasta `public_html`, as vezes `htdocs` ou `www`

Não é necessário enviar a pasta `git` (e **nem deve**), note também que talvez a pasta `vendor` e a pasta `class` estaria melhores fora da `public_html` (ou semelhantes), pois eventualmente dependendo do que for colocado nelas existe uma remota possibilidade de algo poder ser executado quando não deveria, o que pode ocasionar problemas, como BUGs ou até possivelmente alguma falha de segurança.

---

No entanto se você tive-se instalado via skeleton pela linha de comando com `composer`, por exemplo:

```
composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton [pasta-projeto]
```

A pasta raiz seria a `public`, então o esquema a se usar seria mais ou menos este:

```
/home/user/
   |--- /vendor
   |--- /class
   +--- /public_html     (pasta padrão em servidores com cpanel)
          |--- index.php (arquivo da pasta [pasta-projeto]/public)
          +--- .htaccess (arquivo da pasta [pasta-projeto]/public)
```

Comment: Funcionou,estava em duvida se devia enviar a vendor e os arquivos do composer